# RSpec view specs: accessing view helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm testing a Rails (3.2.18) app and I'm having some trouble referencing view helpers in my RSpec (2.14.1) view specs.

The view specs fail because views can't access helper methods defined in `app/helpers`, nor those controller methods that have been marked as helpers.

I guess that I can stub my way out of this, but I was wondering if it can be solved with a simple configuration tweak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add this setting to your `spec/spec_helper.rb` configs:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ApplicationHelper
end
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The helper method was defined in the Application controller. I made it a helper method using action_controller's helper_method. What can I do in my case

Comment: This should be included in the view spec file itself, or in some way limited to just view specs. No reason to apply this to every single test, and can potentially conflict with other methods.